# In The Force Awakens, why does the same lightsaber look different in different scenes?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, lightsaber

Near the culmination of the movie, we see that

> When Finn uses Luke's lightsaber, the saber appears rather usual. However, later when Rey picks up the sword, the blade appears a lot narrower, as if to fit with her thinner physique.

Has something similar ever happened before? I'm only familiar with the movies, but has any other source shown a similar effect in lightsabers before?

Comment: Novelization mentions no such thing. Are you sure this is a real change and not an atrifact of perspective shift?

Comment: I don't remember the blade being any narrower. They did say something about changing/improving the way the lightsaber effect is done, so maybe you're interpreting that as "narrower"?

Comment: I didn't notice a difference in this, but the visual style of the blades changed between the original trilogy and the prequel trilogy, so if there *is* a difference, it's probably just because this is a new trilogy that's being made 33 years later, so there's probably a different team working on the effects. I'll pay more attention when I see the movie again soon.

Comment: @TylerH I'm not comparing the blade to the old movies but the wideness of the blade in the same movie.

Comment: @Nit Ah, I see. All the same, I'll pay close attention during my next viewing

Comment: After watching the movie again, paying attention to this, I couldn't spot a difference in the blade when Rey wielded it.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks for confirming, I suppose it was simply a matter of perspective / other distortion in that case.

Comment: @Nit I will definitely look again once it's finally out of theaters :-)

Comment: @Nit It's definitely not just you.  I was just saying the same to a friend of mine.  To me, it seemed like it changed based on who was holding it while it was ignited.  And, of course, both looked different than the much more ragged looking blade of Kylo Ren's.

Comment: If the air was very dry on StarKiller, the light would be refracted less. Same with using a torch in the fog.

Comment: There's a button on the side to adjust the length. Perhaps you can twiddle with it to adjust the width also

Answer (score 4):

Are these the scenes?

[image]
[image]

I don't see any difference. Note that the thickness of the blade fluctuates a little, as if it's shimmering; perhaps this effect made it appear narrower/thicker. You can most easily see it when Rey is holding it; it doesn't have a uniform thickness.